# How to determine numerical closeness of binary data without knowing the underlying data type

Tags: floating-point, opencl, binary-data

I'm currently implementing a replay functionality for OpenCL kernels, where you can specify a kernel which you want to replay independently from the original program, which is then captured alongside the relevant information required to execute this kernel independently. I've got it working for the most part, but currently struggle with one part:

To make sure there are no silly mistakes, I want to validate the results from the replayed kernel with the results from the original kernel. In my original use case, I could be sure that when running the same kernel multiple times, the results were exactly the same, bit for bit. This meant that I just could calculate a hash of the OpenCL Buffers/Images and check for equality.

But this does not hold for most kernels, since floating point math is not associative and the order of operations is not guaranteed to be the same every time. In this case, using hashes doesn't work and I would need some kind of epsilon closeness test, which is pretty standard.

The problem is, that with my current implementation, I don't know what the data type is of the binary buffers, which can be anything between int8 and fp64.

The question is now, what would be a strategy to determine that the differences between the two buffers (replayed and captured from the original program), only differ by a small amount resulting from the lack of associativity in floating point math.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have Buffer1 and Buffer2 of the same length. For argument's sake let's assume their lengths in bytes is a multiple of 24 and are the same data type all the way through. Your issue with inexactness doesn't apply to integer maths and shouldn't apply to strings either so they should be identical. You can compare them by calculating and comparing their hash values. The issue if floating point results. Let's assume the buffers are all the same type, fp16, bf16, fp24, fp32, or fp64 but you don't know which type. You could calculate an 'error' value, e.g. for fp16,

```
e_fp16 += 1 if ((a == 0) && (b != 0))
e_fp16 += 1 if ((a != 0) && (b == 0))
e_fp16 += (abs((b-a)/a)) if ((a != 0) && (b != 0))
```

one for each type of floating point format. Then take the smallest value as the 'error'.

```
e = min(e_fp16, e_bf16, e_fp24, e_fp32, e_fp64)
```

Comment: This should work, but of course isn't very elegant. If one has some massive buffers, this introduces quite the overhead. Should be okay though, if nothing else works, so thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Code is going to need to know the type of the underlying data.

Without that, a single bit difference is unknown if it is significant or tiny.

---

> some kind of epsilon closeness test  (for floating point)

Assign each floating point value an *index*: 0 for 0.0, 1 for the least encodable positive floating point value, ..., up to N, for the maximum value.  Then -1 for least encodable negative floating point value, ...  (this is easy with a few bit manipulations, yet implementation dependent)

Then use simply integer subtraction to assess closeness.

Comment: There is a way for me to get the data type in OpenCL (from `clGetKernelArgInfo` with the parameter `CL_​KERNEL_​ARG_​TYPE_​NAME`), but this is only available when the kernel was build from source and with a special build flag, but I can spoof that one. Unfortunately an artificial restriction from the standard, because I think most implementations have this info in their device binaries. But I agree, no clean way to do this without this information. So either bruteforce as mentioned above, or hope that the kernel was build from source. In any case, thanks for your answer :)